# How to write MongoDB aggregation in Kotlin/JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use Kotlin JS with the MongoDB Browser SDK. 
The SDK allows a function in JavaScript like:

```
const someData = db("database")
        .collection("stories")
        .aggregate(
                [
                    {
                        $lookup:
                            { from: "person",
                              localField: "person_id",
                              foreignField: "_id",
                              as: "people"
                            }
                    }
                ]
        )
```

This is how I am converting it into Kotlin:

```
val aggregate = mapOf(
        "\$lookup" to mapOf(
                "from" to "people",
                "localField" to "people_id",
                "foreignField" to "_id",
                "as" to "people"
        )
)
val someData = mongodb
    .db("database")
    .collection("stories")
    .aggregate(aggregate)
```

But I get the following error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin/JS `mapOf` is not compatible with plain JavaScript key-value objects. Use [json](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/json.html) function instead.

```
import kotlin.js.json

val aggregate = arrayOf(
    json(
        "\$lookup" to json(
            "from" to "people",
            "localField" to "people_id",
            "foreignField" to "_id",
            "as" to "people"
        )
    )
)
```